# Почему один конструктор родительского класса вызывается с параметром, а все последующие за ним без?

Tags: java

Хотелось бы узнать, с чем связана такая последовательность вызова конструкторов. Почему именно один конструктор вызывается с параметром, а все последующие за ним конструкторы родительских классов -- без параметра?

**Код:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cc c = new Cc(3);
        Aa b = new Cc();
    }
}
class Aa {
    public Aa(){
        System.out.println("Aa");
    }
    public Aa(int A){
        System.out.println("Aa int");
    }
}

class Bb extends Aa{
    public Bb(){
        System.out.println("Bb");
    }
    public Bb(int B){
        System.out.println("Bb int");
    }
}

class Cc extends Bb{
    public Cc(){
        System.out.println("Cc");
    }
    public Cc(int C){
        System.out.println("Cc int");
    }
}
```

**Вывод программы:**

```
Aa
Bb
Cc int
Aa
Bb
Cc
```

Answer (score 2):

В отсутствие явного вызова `super` вызывается родительский конструктор без параметров.

```
class Bb extends Aa{
    public Bb(){
        System.out.println("Bb");
    }
    public Bb(int B){
        super(B); // !!!
        System.out.println("Bb int");
    }
}

class Cc extends Bb{
    public Cc(){
        System.out.println("Cc");
    }
    public Cc(int C){
        super(C); // !!!
        System.out.println("Cc int");
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавлю что в случаи отсутствия конструктора без параметров у предка и super() у потомка . Будет синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: Implicit super constructor AreaCounter.Aa() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor